# Oracle SQL: At time zone does not convert properly for timestamps before 1 June 1905

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I need to convert timestamps stored in my database in UTC format to SGT format (UTC + 8) before my frontend service can consume it.

The query i use is this:

```
SELECT DATE_OF_PURCHASE at time zone 'Asia/Singapore' FROM PROPERTY_LISTINGS;
```

This works fine as long as the timestamp is before 1 June 1905. Any years before that, and i get a converted timestamp thats always 25 secs behind.

An example:

```
1899-09-02 17:04:35.000000 in UTC
```

Converted back to SGT should yield:

```
1899-09-03 00:00:00.000000 in SGT
```

Running the query above using `at time zone` gives:

```
1899-09-02 23:59:35.000000 +06:55:25
```

Which is 25 secs off. This leads to the returned timestamp being a whole day off, which is not expected. Is there a workaround for this in SQL?

Comment: Are you getting that result (time-of-day of 23:59:35) from your input on your system? I get something different - I get UTC +08:00 (which is the current offset). In any case: (1) stupidly, Oracle decided that offsets are always in hours and minutes, which misses a lot of Asian adjustments which are down to the second. (2) the work-around is to add (or subtract) an interval of "x" seconds manually, with a `case` expression depending on comparing `DATE_OF_PURCHASE` to the change date in 1905. Note though that Singapore had numerous offsets in its history, not just pre-1905 and post-1095.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Singapore changed their timezone several times, see [Singapore Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time#Timeline).

```
Asia/Singapore  6:55:25 -       LMT     1901 Jan  1
                6:55:25 -       SMT     1905 Jun  1 # Singapore M.T.
                7:00    -       +07     1933 Jan  1
                7:00    0:20    +0720   1936 Jan  1
                7:20    -       +0720   1941 Sep  1
                7:30    -       +0730   1942 Feb 16
                9:00    -       +09     1945 Sep 12
                7:30    -       +0730   1982 Jan  1
                8:00    -       +08
```

When you check Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004) then it says: *The time zone offset is the difference (in hours and minutes) between local time and UTC*. Looks like seconds are simply not supported /considered in time zone conversions.

Oracle uses the IANA time zone database which states:

> **Scope of the tz database**
>
> The tz database attempts to record the history and predicted future of
> all computer-based clocks that track civil time. It organizes time
> zone and daylight saving time data by partitioning the world into
> timezones whose clocks all agree about timestamps that occur after the
> POSIX Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). The database labels each
> timezone with a notable location and records all known clock
> transitions for that location. Although 1970 is a somewhat-arbitrary
> cutoff, there are significant challenges to moving the cutoff earlier
> even by a decade or two, due to the wide variety of local practices
> before computer timekeeping became prevalent.
>
> Clock transitions before 1970 are recorded for each timezone, because
> most systems support timestamps before 1970 and could misbehave if
> data entries were omitted for pre-1970 transitions. However, the
> database is not designed for and does not suffice for applications
> requiring accurate handling of all past times everywhere, as it would
> take far too much effort and guesswork to record all details of
> pre-1970 civil timekeeping. Although some information outside the
> scope of the database is collected in a file backzone that is
> distributed along with the database proper, this file is less reliable
> and does not necessarily follow database guidelines.

I don't think there is an easy solution.